How to substitute only a part of a string with capturing group using R base?
Let's say I want to select only "LCZBDT" in the following string : "LCZBDT.105".
gsub(x="LCZBDT.105",
     pattern="(\\w)(\\.)(\\d+)", replacement = "\\1")

works well.
But if I want to select 105, the following code
gsub(x="LCZBDT.105",
     pattern="(\\w)(\\.)(\\d+)", replacement = "\\3")

returns "LCZBD105"
I have no idea why. I know I could use the stringr package, but I try to reduce my dependences to the tidyverse.

As it turns out, it seems the definition of a word as captured by \\w is unclear, and the following code extracts the proper sequence :
gsub(x="LCZBDT22.105",
     pattern="([A-Z]*\\d*)(\\.)(\\d+)", replacement = "\\3")

It's as if a word can not have an uppercase within it (and it kind of makes sense), so the string "LCZB" would not be captured at all and is repassed to the output of gsub, according to what the help page says :

Blockquote  Elements of character vectors x which are not substituted will be returned unchanged

the "T" and the "." are matched as group 1 and 2 and are therefore not kept.
Maybe this can help some other R-base coders.

“the definition of a word as captured by \\w is unclear” — No, it’s perfectly clear. I’m not sure where you got your definition from, but \w has a firmly established meaning in regex, and the R regex documentation accurately reflects it: “The symbol \w matches a ‘word’ character (a synonym for [[:alnum:]_] […]”. — In other words (like everything else in a regex) it matches a single character.
